# Why find method giving me a result while there is no object key available

Tags: javascript, reactjs, find

Why find method giving me a result while there is no object key available? as you can see from my below code on the data1 there is no **size property** but when I try to find by **size property** it gives me a result it should give me an empty object.

```js
const data1= [{title: 'extra Tomato', price: 2},
              {title: 'ketchup', price: 1},
              {title: 'extra large', price: 8.1}]

const data2 = [{title: 'extra Tomato', price: 2},
                {title: 'ketchup', price: 1}]

const isOptionExist = data1.find((elm) =>
          data2.map((item) => item.title === elm.size)
        );
console.log(isOptionExist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down the problem you are running into. First, what does the `data2.map((item) => item.title === elm.size)` return?

```js
data1= [{title: 'extra Tomato', price: 2},
          {title: 'ketchup', price: 1},
          {title: 'extra large', price: 8.1}]

const data2 = [{title: 'extra Tomato', price: 2},
                {title: 'ketchup', price: 1}]

const elm = data1[0]
const result = data2.map((item) => item.title === elm.size)

console.log(result)
```

You can see that the return value is `[false, false]`. This is because [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is iterating through `data2` and creating a new array where the value of each element is the value of `item.title === elm.size`, which is `false`.

The next part of code that will be evaulated will be:

```
data1.find((elm) => [false, false])
```

In the below example, we can that this returns `{ "title": "extra Tomato", "price": 2 }`

```js
data1= [{title: 'extra Tomato', price: 2},
          {title: 'ketchup', price: 1},
          {title: 'extra large', price: 8.1}]

const data2 = [{title: 'extra Tomato', price: 2},
                {title: 'ketchup', price: 1}]

const result = data1.find((elm) => [false, false])

console.log(result)
```

So why is `[false, false]` being considered true? That's becasue `[false, false]` is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value in javascript.

Here's an snippet with [!!](https://brianflove.com/2014-09-02/whats-the-double-exclamation-mark-for-in-javascript/) to prove it:

```js
console.log(!![false, false])
```

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy):

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that is considered true when encountered in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy. That is, all values are truthy except false, 0, -0, 0n, "", null, undefined, and NaN.

---

If you want to return three empty arrays from your query you can do this:

```js
const data1= [{title: 'extra Tomato', price: 2},
              {title: 'ketchup', price: 1},
              {title: 'extra large', price: 8.1}]

const data2 = [{title: 'extra Tomato', price: 2},
                {title: 'ketchup', price: 1}]

const isOptionExist = data1.map((elm) => data2.filter((item) => item.title === elm.size))
        
console.log(isOptionExist)
```

If you are jus trying to get a boolean value for if an option was found, try this:

```js
const data1= [{title: 'extra Tomato', price: 2},
              {title: 'ketchup', price: 1},
              {title: 'extra large', price: 8.1}]

const data2 = [{title: 'extra Tomato', price: 2},
                {title: 'ketchup', price: 1}]

const isOptionExistTrue = data1.some((elm) => data2.some((item) => item.title === elm.title))
        
console.log(isOptionExistTrue)

const isOptionExistFalse = data1.some((elm) => data2.some((item) => item.title === elm.size))
        
console.log(isOptionExistFalse)
```

Comment: still, it is giving an object it should give an empty object because there is no `size` property in data1

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct syntax.
What you wrote there is the same as:

```
const isOptionExist = data1.find((elm) => true);
```

Because

```
Boolean(data2.map((item) => item.title === elm.size))
```

is true.

And that would return you the first data1 element. As it did.

Comment: do you know how can I get an empty object or undefined if there is no key property